# OrientDB - Edge Property in Expand

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases

I have 2 'V' classes in my database that are: "User" and "Cinema" and 2 'E' classes that are: "Friend" and "isGoing".
My "Friend" edge is lightweight and is working fine, but whenever I try to select anything using the property inside "isGoing" (Datetime date), the select returns empty.

Examples:

```
SELECT expand(both('Friend').outE('isGoing').inV()) FROM #12:0
```

This returns all the "Cinema" that my friends are going.
Using the same query but adding the property:

```
SELECT expand(both('Friend').outE('isGoing')[date = '2015-05-29 00:00:00'].inV()) FROM #12:0
```

This returns me 0 results. The date I used is the same that was returned on my first select, so I don't think it is a mispelling error.

Is there something I am missing? My DB version is 2.0.6

Comment: To Be sure try this
select from isGoing where date = '2015-05-29 00:00:00'
see if it matches something

Comment: Tried this
    select from isGoing where date = '2015-05-29 00:00:00'
and it returned the Edge but not the Cinema I wanted

Comment: Can you try `.[field = value]` in a simpler query. May be 2.0.6 is not supporting this kind of filtering. What about just this: `SELECT expand(both('Friend').outE('isGoing')[date = '2015-05-29 00:00:00']) FROM #12:0`.

Comment: Same problem, 0 results when the [field = value] is there....and the correct result if I remove it.
I had the 1.7.1 version prior to this one and had the same results, that is why i tried updating it with no luck.

Comment: Update - I tried changing the value field to an integer type and it worked. I guess it might be something with the "Datetime" type and the expand function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be something about the Datetime format and OrientDB but as I just need the Day, changing the field for an integer worked and the query

```
SELECT expand(both('Friend').outE('isGoing')[Day = 29].inV()) FROM #12:0
```

worked as expected